# Change element with jQuery before DOM loads

Tags: jquery, dom

I am trying to add an attribute to a font tag for Google Rich Snippets, I can do this no problem, but because the page has loaded the changes are not in the HTML source. Does any one know a way of adding the attribute before the DOM loads?

Comment: Why can't you change it in the HTML source file?

Comment: Sorry should have explained because its in a template system I cant change.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using a JS solution (like jQuery), because it manipulates only the DOM (after it has been loaded partially or completely), not the page source itself.
The page source has to be changed on the server side.